# What's a good Match 3 game for a five year old?

Tags: android, game

My son has taken an interest in my wife's Farm Heroes Saga. He understands the match 3 premise, but the game is full of in game purchases and Facebook popups after each level with close and cancel buttons all over the place.

I understand that's the way the game makes money, but it's impossible for him to navigate.

Is there a colourful match 3 game, free or paid, that does not have ads or Facebook links? Fun but simple.

Answer (score -1):

Gummy Candy Blast will remove ads with an in game purchase of $4.79.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gummy.candy.android

Comment: I very much doubt that. The app comes with 15 (!!) trackers (including real heavy ones like Facebook, Umeng and Moat). Definitely a no-go for children. If you don't believe me, check out [at Appbrain](https://www.appbrain.com/app/com.gummy.candy.android) (scroll down to "Libraries"). So if you value the child's (and its family's) privacy, pick something else.

Comment: Good to know. Just the first one I saw with the option.

Answer (score -1):

Baby Shark Match: Ocean Jam offers no ads for $2.59.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitmango.go.babysharkmatchoceanjam

Comment: Same issue here, not suited for children in a security/privacy context. I count 14 trackers on a quick glance. Hint: Always check with [Exodus Privacy](https://reports.exodus-privacy.eu.org/en/analysis/submit/) or Appbrain. Both can be related to the Play Store URL (the `id=` value). // Apart from that: One-line answers are rather low quality. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see what we aim at here.

Comment: My apologies. I was really hoping someone had done this research. Match 3 is such a saturated market.

Comment: I must admit I haven't even heard of it – but that might be a language thingy (I'm not a native English speaker). Maybe you could update your question with a few more details to make good matching (oops, no pun intended) answers possible? And while looking around yourself, make sure a finding isn't "too offensive" (cross-checking with Exodus/Appbrain) and then also point that out in your answer (e.g. "other than most apps in this area, this one comes with no/few trackers…") – and consider some other points from the linked quality guide? I gladly upvote then :)

Comment: PS: That seems to be a huge task. Starting with [this list](https://www.appbrain.com/search?q=match-3&src=header) and walking it 1-by-1, 14 trackers is in the medium range (found one with far more than 20). [Here's one](https://www.appbrain.com/app/net.peakgames.lostjewels) that has just 5, [one with 3](https://www.appbrain.com/app/air.com.generamobile.kingcraft) and [one with just 2](https://www.appbrain.com/app/air.com.qublix.forestrescue). Why do they all have Facebook included, in games for small kids??? That's quite unreasonable and irresponsible. PS: I checked 1st page only. Go on :)